# UILabel not loaded/missing when presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

Have anyone worked with Bonsai? Github link at: [Here](https://github.com/rishi420/Bonsai)

I tried to push a `viewController` by using gesture in which

```
    @objc func upSwiped(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up {
        print("Swiped Up")

        let vc = PromoDetailsViewController()
        vc.transitioningDelegate = self
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

To use Bonsai, I needed to made an extension like

```
extension YourViewController: BonsaiControllerDelegate {

// return the frame of your Bonsai View Controller
func frameOfPresentedView(in containerViewFrame: CGRect) -> CGRect {

    return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: containerViewFrame.height / 4), size: CGSize(width: containerViewFrame.width, height: containerViewFrame.height / (4/3)))
}

// return a Bonsai Controller with SlideIn or Bubble transition animator
func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {

    // Slide animation from .left, .right, .top, .bottom
    return BonsaiController(fromDirection: .bottom, blurEffectStyle: .light, presentedViewController: presented, delegate: self)



    // or Bubble animation initiated from a view
    //return BonsaiController(fromView: yourOriginView, blurEffectStyle: .dark,  presentedViewController: presented, delegate: self)
}
}
```

In my next `viewController` it is supposed to show up by slide in from bottom to half my screen, however, the labels there are all missing. I am suspecting it is not loaded and unsure what are the steps to be taken. My results at the moment is

[image]

Comment: did you try to use view debugger? is your viewDidLoad and other methods being called?

Comment: i did a breakpoint and try to see if my labels on next view controller exist, it shows nil..so am guessing it's not loaded

Comment: if you open this view controller without bonsai does It work?

Comment: yes, if i put this view as initial view controller, it works...so am thinking it has something to do with the presenting

Comment: is your view controller on storyboard?

Comment: yes it is on my storyboard. All my viewcontrollers are done by storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `let vc = PromoDetailsViewController()` try instatiating view controller from storyboard like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR STORYBOARD NAME", bundle: Bundle.main)

guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER IDENTIFIER") as? PromoDetailsViewController else {
    fatalError("Error! Could not instantiate PromoDetailsViewController")
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...weird...why this would be ok, but the ways I used isnt

Comment: Because views from storyboard have to be initialised with all of elements from storyboard, if you would create it all in code you could use `let vc = PromoDetailsViewController()`